# asp.net tracking user info

Tags: asp.net, session, cookies

How is the best way to track user information, sesssion Id, cookies? once for user session.
In Default.aspx:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  IF (!isPostPack)
  {
    var sessionValue= System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies["ASP.NET_SessionId"] != null ?                      System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies["ASP.NET_SessionId"].Value : string.Empty;
     cONSOLE.WRITELINE(sessionValue);
    }

}
```

This is not optimize. is there anyway to get only once the session iD,per user?

Comment: Session_OnStart in Global.asax?

Comment: In Global asax Session_OnStart the request to cookies/session is not valid. Object not set to a reference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var sessionValue = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies["ASP.NET_SessionId"] 
!= null ? 
System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies["ASP.NET_SessionId"].Value : string.Empty;
```

All that will give you is the identifier that ASP.Net uses to track the session. This is rarely something you need to directly access in code.

But assuming that *is* what you want, it will be extremely fast. To make it cleaner, you can:

- Access `Request` directly (no need for `HttpContext` inside a `Page`)
- Store the value in a class-level variable that will live for the lifecycle of the page.

```
private string _sessionId;

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    _sessionId = Request.Cookies["ASP.NET_SessionId"] != null 
        Request.Cookies["ASP.NET_SessionId"].Value : string.Empty;
}
```

If you want to do this only once per session (per the comments):

```
protected void Session_Start( object sender, EventArgs e )
{
    using( var writer = File.CreateText( @"c:\temp\session-id.txt" ) )
    {
        writer.WriteLine( Session.SessionID );
    }
}
```

Comment: Tim, and if a store the value in stream file, how can the Page_Load assure that only once i get the session Id and write it ?

Comment: So you are trying to store the session ID only once per session (e.g. to a log file?)

Comment: I added an example, which I ran successfully on my machine.